# Scalable Outlier/Anomaly Detection

Tags: data-mining, bigdata, algorithms, outlier

I am trying to setup a big data infrastructure using Hadoop, Hive, Elastic Search (amongst others), and I would like to run some algorithms over certain datasets. I would like the algorithms themselves to be scalable, so this excludes using tools such as Weka, R, or even RHadoop. The [Apache Mahout Library](https://mahout.apache.org) seems to be a good option, and it features [algorithms for regression and clustering tasks](https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/algorithms.html).

What I am struggling to find is a solution for anomaly or outlier detection.

Since Mahout features Hidden Markov Models and a variety of clustering techniques (including K-Means) I was wondering if it would be possible to build a model to detect outliers in time-series, using any of this. I would be grateful if somebody experienced on this could advice me

1. if it is possible, and in case it is
2. how-to do it, plus
3. an estimation of the effort involved and
4. accuracy/problems of this approach.

Comment: This is too vague to be answered. Time series are too different to just throw k-means on them and get out anything useful. It *heavily* depends on your data.

Comment: For outlier detection, have a look at the algorithms in ELKI. That seems to be the most complete collection of outlier detection.

Comment: The newer Elasticsearch versions have time series anomaly detection built in (I think you have to buy the X-Pack).  I am not sure what algorithms they are using but it might be worth investigating an off-the-shelf solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would take a look at [t-digest algorithm](https://github.com/tdunning/t-digest). It's [been merged into mahout](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-1361) and also a part of [some other libraries](http://github.com/addthis/stream-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/clearspring/analytics/stream/quantile/TDigest.java) for big data streaming. You can get more about this algorithm particularly and big data anomaly detection in general in next resources:

1. [Practical machine learning anomaly detection book.](http://info.mapr.com/rs/mapr/images/Practical_Machine_Learning_Anomaly_Detection.pdf)
2. [Webinar: Anomaly Detection When You Don't Know What You Need to Find](http://youtube.com/watch?v=i-mSV63Q9rA#t=757)
3. [Anomaly Detection in Elasticsearch](http://info.prelert.com/anomaly-detection-in-elasticsearch).
4. [Beating Billion Dollar Fraud Using Anomaly Detection: A Signal Processing Approach using Argyle Data on the Hortonworks Data Platform with Accumulo](http://oreilly.com/pub/e/3211)

Comment: How does t-digest compare to the p-square algorithm?

Comment: Thanks for the answer: this is a simple model to compute extreme quantiles, and I think it will fit my needs. However for more complex time-series that do not have a nearly stationary distribution this approach may fail, and that's when I think we would need something adaptive such as a Markov chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my response related to h2o R or Python anomaly detection method in [stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/open-source-anomaly-detection-in-python),since that is scalable too.