# Open source Anomaly Detection in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-mining, anomaly-detection, library

**Problem Background:**
I am working on a project that involves log files similar to those found in the IT monitoring space (to my best understanding of IT space). These log files are time-series data, organized into hundreds/thousands of rows of various parameters. Each parameter is numeric (float) and there is a non-trivial/non-error value for each time point. My task is to monitor said log files for anomaly detection (spikes, falls, unusual patterns with some parameters being out of sync, strange 1st/2nd/etc. derivative behavior, etc.).

On a similar assignment, I have tried Splunk with Prelert, but I am exploring open-source options at the moment.

**Constraints:**
I am limiting myself to Python because I know it well, and would like to delay the switch to R and the associated learning curve. Unless there seems to be overwhelming support for R (or other languages/software), I would like to stick to Python for this task.

Also, I am working in a Windows environment for the moment. I would like to continue to sandbox in Windows on small-sized log files but can move to Linux environment if needed.

**Resources:**
I have checked out the following with dead-ends as results:

1. Some info [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/python-or-r-for-implementing-machine-learning-algorithms-for-fraud-detection) is helpful, but unfortunately, I am struggling to find the right package because:
2. Twitter's "AnomalyDetection" is in R, and I want to stick to Python. Furthermore, the Python port [pyculiarity](https://github.com/nicolasmiller/pyculiarity) seems to cause issues in implementing in Windows environment for me.
3. Skyline, my next attempt, seems to have been pretty much discontinued (from [github issues](https://github.com/etsy/skyline/issues/119)). I haven't dived deep into this, given how little support there seems to be online.
4. scikit-learn I am still exploring, but this seems to be much more manual. The down-in-the-weeds approach is OK by me, but my background in learning tools is weak, so would like something like a black box for the technical aspects like algorithms, similar to Splunk+Prelert.

**Problem Definition and Questions:**
I am looking for open-source software that can help me with automating the process of anomaly detection from time-series log files in Python via packages or libraries.

5. Do such things exist to assist with my immediate task, or are they imaginary in my mind?
6. Can anyone assist with concrete steps to help me to my goal, including background fundamentals or concepts?
7. Is this the best StackExchange community to ask in, or is Stats, Math, or even Security or Stackoverflow the better options?

**EDIT [2015-07-23]**
Note that the latest update to [pyculiarity](https://github.com/nicolasmiller/pyculiarity) seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/nicolasmiller/pyculiarity/issues/1) for the Windows environment! I have yet to confirm, but should be another useful tool for the community.

**EDIT [2016-01-19]**
A minor update. I had not time to work on this and research, but I am taking a step back to understand the fundamentals of this problem before continuing to research in specific details. For example, two concrete steps that I am taking are:

1. Starting with the [Wikipedia articles for anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection), understanding fully, and then either moving up or down in concept hierarchy of other linked Wikipedia articles, such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm), and then [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning).
2. Exploring techniques in the great surveys done by Chandola et al 2009 [*Anomaly Detection: A Survey*](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/%7Ebanerjee/papers/09/anomaly.pdf) and Hodge et al 2004 [*A Survey of Outlier Detection Methodologies*](http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/767/1/hodgevj4.pdf).

Once the concepts are better understood (I hope to play around with toy examples as I go to develop the practical side as well), I hope to understand which open source Python tools are better suited for my problems.

**EDIT [2020-02-04]**
It has been a few years since I worked on this problem, and am no longer working on this project, so I will not be following or researching this area until further notice. Thank you very much to all for their input. I hope this discussion helps others that need guidance on anomaly detection work.

FWIW, if I had to do the same project now with the same resources (few thousand USD in expenses), I would pursue the deep learning/neural network approach. The ability of the method to automatically learn structure and hierarchy via hidden layers would've been very appealing since we had lots of data and (now) could spend the money on cloud compute. I would still use Python though ;).

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe this helps cause you mentioned about steady states:
https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-practical-and-robust-anomaly-detection-in-a-time-series

Comment: Thanks for your time, but please see my first bullet of "Resources"; I have reviewed this option, and looking for something that meets my "Constraints".

Comment: I recommend these videos if you are just beginning Scikit: https://github.com/justmarkham/scikit-learn-videos

Comment: To reiterate, and perhaps be more blunt, using Twitter's AnomalyDetection package is NOT an option here: Please read the "Constraints" section more carefully. I do not mean to denounce any sincere attempts to help on this, but the question is strictly for Python-based packages. Therefore, future voters, PLEASE do not upvote this answer because it is not usable option. I would recommending clearing the current 2 votes for this via downvoting but perhaps this is unethical within the Stackexchange community and do not want to catch any flack.

Comment: Again, I apologize to harp on this, but I am simply trying to make this question very clear and usable for others encountering a similar problem, and don't want them to go on a wild goose chase.

Comment: h2o library not importing in this module.

Comment: Your problem is ill defined. What constitutes an anomaly can have a lot of different meanings. Is it deviation of the mean? Is it certain patterns of behaviour? Different methods apply in each case. You'll need to look into "outlier detection" if the anomaly is deviation from the mean. If you are looking for specific patterns you'd be much better served with a supervised learning algorithm such as neural networks.

Comment: I know you want Python, but for anomaly detection ELKI seems to be the tool to use.

Answer (score 37):

Anomaly Detection or Event Detection can be done in different ways:

### Basic Way

Derivative! If the deviation of your signal from its past & future is high you most probably have an event. This can be extracted by finding large zero crossings in derivative of the signal.

### Statistical Way

Mean of anything is its usual, basic behavior. if something deviates from mean it means that it's an event. Please note that mean in time-series is not that trivial and is not a constant but changing according to changes in time-series so you need to see the *"moving average"* instead of average. It looks like this:

[image: Events are peaks larger than 1 standard deviation from moving average]

The Moving Average code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352047/finding-moving-average-from-data-points-in-python). In signal processing terminology you are applying a *"Low-Pass"* filter by applying the moving average.

You can follow the code bellow:

```
MOV = movingaverage(TimeSEries,5).tolist()
STD = np.std(MOV)
events= []
ind = []
for ii in range(len(TimeSEries)):
    if TimeSEries[ii] > MOV[ii]+STD:
        events.append(TimeSEries[ii])
```

### Probabilistic Way

They are more sophisticated specially for people new to Machine Learning. Kalman Filter is a great idea to [find the anomalies](http://www.hamilton.ie/florian/infocom2008.pdf). Simpler probabilistic approaches using *"Maximum-Likelihood Estimation"* also work well but my suggestion is to stay with moving average idea. It works in practice very well.

I hope I could help :)
Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you for your efforts on the deep discussion. Though programming this doesn't seem too bad (quite interesting, I may say, to deep dive into the algorithms), I am curious of packages that already are available. Do you know of anything that exists that is simple to install? Note this is not the same as simple to implement, which I understand cannot be guaranteed. If I can get my environment functional, I believe I can finesse it based on examples for my task.

Answer (score 18):

I recently developed a toolbox: **Py**thon **O**utlier **D**etection toolbox (**PyOD**). See [GitHub](https://github.com/yzhao062/Pyod).

It is designed for identifying outlying objects in data with both unsupervised and supervised approaches. PyOD is featured for:

- Unified APIs, detailed documentation, and interactive examples across
  various algorithms.
- Advanced models, including Neural Networks/Deep
  Learning and Outlier Ensembles.
- Optimized performance with JIT and
  parallelization when possible, using numba and joblib.
  Compatible
  with both Python 2 & 3 (scikit-learn compatible as well).

Here are some important links:

- **[Github](https://github.com/yzhao062/Pyod)**
- **[PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pyod/)**
- **[Documentation](https://pyod.readthedocs.io)**
- **[Interactive Jupyter Notebooks](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/yzhao062/Pyod/master)**

If you use PyOD in a scientific publication, we would appreciate
citations to the following paper

```
@article{zhao2019pyod,
  title={PyOD: A Python Toolbox for Scalable Outlier Detection},
  author={Zhao, Yue and Nasrullah, Zain and Li, Zheng},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1901.01588},
  year={2019},
  url={https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.01588}
}
```

It is currently under review at [JMLR](http://www.jmlr.org/mloss/)
(machine learning open-source software track). See [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.01588).

---

#### Quick Introduction

PyOD toolkit consists of three major groups of functionalities: (i) outlier
detection algorithms; (ii) outlier ensemble frameworks and (iii) outlier
detection utility functions.

***Individual Detection Algorithms***:

- **PCA**: Principal Component Analysis (the sum of weighted projected distances to the eigenvector hyperplanes)
- **MCD**: Minimum Covariance Determinant (use the mahalanobis distances as the outlier scores)
- **OCSVM**: One-Class Support Vector Machines
- **LOF**: Local Outlier Factor
- **CBLOF**: Clustering-Based Local Outlier Factor
- **LOCI**: LOCI: Fast outlier detection using the local correlation integral
- **HBOS**: Histogram-based Outlier Score
- **kNN**: k Nearest Neighbors (use the distance to the kth nearest neighbor as the - **outlier score
- **AvgKNN**: Average kNN (use the average distance to k nearest neighbors as the outlier score)
- **MedKNN**: Median kNN (use the median distance to k nearest neighbors as the outlier score)
- **ABOD**: Angle-Based Outlier Detection
- **FastABOD**: Fast Angle-Based Outlier Detection using approximation
- **SOS**: Stochastic Outlier Selection
- **IForest**: Isolation Forest
- **Feature Bagging**
- **LSCP**: LSCP: Locally Selective Combination of Parallel Outlier Ensembles
- **XGBOD**: Extreme Boosting Based Outlier Detection (Supervised)
- **AutoEncoder**: Fully connected AutoEncoder (use reconstruction error as the outlier score)
- **SO_GAAL**: Single-Objective Generative Adversarial Active Learning
- **MO_GAAL**: Multiple-Objective Generative Adversarial Active Learning

***Outlier Detector/Scores Combination Frameworks***:

- **Feature Bagging**
- **LSCP**: LSCP: Locally Selective Combination of Parallel Outlier Ensembles
- **Average**: Simple combination by averaging the scores
- **Weighted Average**: Simple combination by averaging the scores with detector weights
- **Maximization**: Simple combination by taking the maximum scores
- **AOM**: Average of Maximum
- **MOA**: Maximization of Average

***Utility Functions for Outlier Detection***:

1. `score_to_lable()`: convert raw outlier scores to binary labels
2. `precision_n_scores()`: one of the popular evaluation metrics for outlier
   mining (precision @ rank n)
3. `generate_data()`: generate pseudo data for outlier detection experiment
4. `wpearsonr()`: weighted pearson is useful in pseudo ground truth generation

**Comparison of all implemented models** are made available below:
([Figure](https://github.com/yzhao062/Pyod/blob/master/examples/ALL.png),
[Code](https://github.com/yzhao062/Pyod/blob/master/examples/compare_all_models.py),
[Jupyter Notebooks](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/yzhao062/Pyod/master)):[image]

If you are interested, please check [Github](https://github.com/yzhao062/Pyod) for more information.

Answer (score 17):

h2o has an [anomaly detection module](http://learn.h2o.ai/content/hands-on_training/anomaly_detection.html) and traditionally the code is available in R.However beyond version 3 it has similar module available in python as well,and since h2o is open source it might fit your bill.

You can see an working example over [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/tests/testdir_algos/deeplearning/pyunit_anomaly_largeDeepLearning.py)

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,"../../../")
import h2o

def anomaly(ip, port):
    h2o.init(ip, port)

    print "Deep Learning Anomaly Detection MNIST"

    train = h2o.import_frame(h2o.locate("bigdata/laptop/mnist/train.csv.gz"))
    test = h2o.import_frame(h2o.locate("bigdata/laptop/mnist/test.csv.gz"))

    predictors = range(0,784)
    resp = 784

    # unsupervised -> drop the response column (digit: 0-9)
    train = train[predictors]
    test = test[predictors]

    # 1) LEARN WHAT'S NORMAL
    # train unsupervised Deep Learning autoencoder model on train_hex
    ae_model = h2o.deeplearning(x=train[predictors], training_frame=train, activation="Tanh", autoencoder=True,
                                hidden=[50], l1=1e-5, ignore_const_cols=False, epochs=1)

    # 2) DETECT OUTLIERS
    # anomaly app computes the per-row reconstruction error for the test data set
    # (passing it through the autoencoder model and computing mean square error (MSE) for each row)
    test_rec_error = ae_model.anomaly(test)

    # 3) VISUALIZE OUTLIERS
    # Let's look at the test set points with low/median/high reconstruction errors.
    # We will now visualize the original test set points and their reconstructions obtained
    # by propagating them through the narrow neural net.

    # Convert the test data into its autoencoded representation (pass through narrow neural net)
    test_recon = ae_model.predict(test)

    # In python, the visualization could be done with tools like numpy/matplotlib or numpy/PIL

if __name__ == '__main__':
    h2o.run_test(sys.argv, anomaly)
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't considered this package yet - I will add it to the list of candidates. To clarify, when you say "beyond version 3 it has similar module available in python as well", do you know if h2o's anomaly detection module (beyond ver 3) is available in Python, or some other module?

Comment: @ximik Well,I revisited the python documentation of their latest version 3.0.0.26(http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-shannon/26/docs-website/h2o-py/docs/index.html) and it seems like h2o.anomaly is not yet available unlike its R api.I've raised the question in their google group(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/uma3UdpanEI) and you can follow that.

Comment: Well,h2o support group has answered the question and anomaly is available in python as well.An example is available here.
https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/tests/testdir_algos/deeplearning/pyunit_anomaly_largeDeepLearning.py

Comment: Perfect! thank you for investigating. i'll update this post with results.

Comment: the link to the h2o test does not work any more, but there is a (probably) equivalent one: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/tests/testdir_algos/deeplearning/pyunit_anomaly_deeplearning_large.py (permalink to the version at the time of writing is https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/399f5b200173e666d7b94071f124db9640391d9c/h2o-py/tests/testdir_algos/deeplearning/pyunit_anomaly_deeplearning_large.py )

Answer (score 8):

I am currently on same stage like you. I am finding best option for anomaly detection, doing some research.

What I have found is I think best matches your need and is better compare to what you have seen. i.e., TwitterAnomalyDetection, SkyLine.

I have found better is Numenta's NAB (Numenta Anomaly Benchmark).
It also have a very good community support and for you plus point is its open source & developed in Python. You can add your algorithm in it.

In case of algorithm, I found LOF, or CBLOF are good option.

So, [check it out](https://github.com/numenta/nab) once. It may help you out.

If you found better option, please share.

Answer (score 6):

I assume the feature you use to detect abnormality is one row of data in a logfile. If so, Sklearn is your good friend and you can use it as a blackbox. Check the tutorial of [one-class SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html) and [Novelty detection](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html).

However, in case that your feature is an entire logfile, you need to first summarize it to some feature of same dimension, and then apply Novealty detection.

Answer (score 3):

There is still an active and developed version of Skyline, just in case someone lands here and is interested.

[Skyline](https://github.com/earthgecko/skyline) ([documentation](https://earthgecko-skyline.readthedocs.io/en/latest))

I am the current maintainer of the project and it is now a lot more advanced than the original Etsy version, in terms of performance, UI, better handling of seasonality and has the added functionalities of an anomalies database, calculating correlations and the ability to fingerprint and learn not anomalous patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multivariate time series, I would go for a LSTM-RNN implementation that models the dynamics of your system based on training data, which are usually semi-supervised (only normal class included). This means that you train your model to learn what is "normal". During testing, you test both normal and anomalous conditions to see how well the model tells them apart.

An advantage of neural networks is that they "learn" the cross-correlations between input signals by themselves; you do not need to explore them manually. LSTM-RNNs, in particular, are an ideal choice when it comes to time series modelling simply because of their ability to keep memory of previous inputs, similar to a state space model in Control Theory (if you see the analogy).

In Python, it is almost trivial to implement an LSTM-RNN using [Keras](https://keras.io/) API (on top of Tensorflow backend). This network learns to estimate the signal(s) of interest given an arbitrary number of inputs, which you thereafter compare with the actual measured value. If there is "big" deviation, you got an anomaly (given that the model is accurate enough)!