# Anomaly detection in Time Series Data - Help Required

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, time-series, anomaly-detection

I am looking for algorithms on Anomaly detection for time series data. It is uni-variate analysis, considering single parameter (inlet pressure) of air compressor sensor data. The objective is to detect if there is any significant deviation in parameter value in real time.

If any one has worked on similar projects, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Can you describe in more or less specific terms the nature of your time series, and of your anomalies?

Comment: Semi supervised SVMs are quite efficient on IT security matters. You need a few supervised learning to get a good anomaly detection. See that for an example:
http://rslab.disi.unitn.it/papers/R86-TGRS-Jordi.pdf

Comment: You may have a look at this https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/open-source-anomaly-detection-in-python/6549#6549

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to DS forum. There are many methods available for anomaly detection of uni-variate, low dimension and high dimension data sets.

**Supervised algorithms** can be used if the past anomalies are recorded with flag variables and there is significant examples of flagged anomalies.

In **unsupervised algorithms** the key aspect of anomaly is which subset of the larger data set is considered when looking for anomolies i.e., global vs local and point vs contextual

[image: Anomaly Types]

Here are some useful links to get you started, [anomaly detection in machine generated data](http://www.diva-portal.se/smash/get/diva2:621699/FULLTEXT01.pdf) and [introductory overview of time-series based anomaly detection algorithms](http://www.autonlab.org/tutorials/biosurv.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Manohar Swamynathan and  Laurent Duval. Thanks for your response. The analysis is unsupervised in nature and considering a single variable (inlet pressure). The objective is to develop a model which can detect if there is any significant deviation in the parameter value in real time.

Comment: @ Sunil for your use case, the uni-variate methods discussed in the paper [anomaly detection in machine generated data](http://www.diva-portal.se/smash/get/diva2:621699/FULLTEXT01.pdf) has been implemented in python and the same can be found in [here](https://github.com/aeriksson/ad-eval)

Comment: @ Manohar, thanks for the document. Ya, I am going through the material. Can you let me know if there is any document where the method is implemented in R ?

Comment: I'm not sure of implementation of this paper content in R, however you can look at [AnomalyDetection](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection) R package and also there is a new package by Rob J Hyndman [Anomalous time series package](https://github.com/robjhyndman/anomalous).