# Analysis of railway data - Detecting outliers

Tags: data-mining, regression, self-study

I would like some pointers about the following problem:

I would like to detect anomalies in a pretty huge collection of railway data. Or create a baseline model for detecting future anomalies. The data I have at my disposal exists out of coordinates and speed at the given coordinate (also the time of measurement). Could this perhaps be approached as a regression problem where there's a clear(?) connection between location and speed of a train. For instance a train suddenly moving at snail's pace on a track that from historical data is considered high velocity could be a potential anomaly. If this could indeed be approached in such a way would something like SVM be an option or should I look into other algorithms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of directions you can take, and there are a number of questions related to this topic ([anamoly-detection-for-transaction-data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/anamoly-detection-for-transaction-data)).  One question to answer first is whether the data is seasonal or not.

You already suggested a valid approach.  Determine which areas are correlated to low and high speeds and than determine when a speed differs.  I think it's best to start with a heuristic approach and than try more complicated methods to try to improve.  If you want to use an SVM, a one-class SVM may work well ([one-class SVM](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html#sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM))