# How does Elastic's Prelert (formerly Splunk Anomaly Detective App) work?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, time-series, anomaly-detection

**Background:** In recent months, [Elastic has purchased Prelert](https://www.elastic.co/blog/welcome-prelert-to-the-elastic-team) and will actively incorporate it into the Elastic stack (and also discontinue the Splunk Anomaly Detective App!). I am trying to understand the theoretical methodology and process framework for their predictive analytics approach to time series anomaly detection so I can be an effective and efficient user of the Prelert tool.

**Question:** What topics to explore, and what is the general process flow/pipeline? How would one start to learn and understand the building blocks of the big concepts involved. I understand from a few posts online ([1](http://info.prelert.com/how-automated-anomaly-detection-works),[2](http://www.prelert.com/resources/Anomaly_Detection_In_APM_Data.pdf)) a bit about how it works, but want to understand the major process items involved. At a high level, I get that there is some training set that fits a distribution via unsupervised ML, and that distribution is used to assess probability of future events - but need to get into the sequential processing blocks involved (for example, data read step, followed by sending it to a distribution-matching step, then some unsupervised ML step where a distribution is selected/adjusted, etc). I understand specifics may be difficult, so guesses and hypothetical ideas from people with experience in this arena would be great.

**Note 1:** I am ***not*** interested in the Prelert's "secret sauce" and the exact proprietary algorithms that they have developed - this would be unethical and I do not want to recreate their product, I just want to understand how to better use it. I am interested in an explanation of the main concepts implemented at a high level but in more detail than the posts ([1](http://info.prelert.com/how-automated-anomaly-detection-works),[2](http://www.prelert.com/resources/Anomaly_Detection_In_APM_Data.pdf)) I found. Example post of the explanation could be in the form:

- 'distribution is populated via X concept/algorithm and then followed
  by selection step by Y machine learning concept/algorithm. Possible
  concepts to study are A,B,C. Key search words for literature searches
  are Q,W,E. Some references are N,M,L.'

**Note 2:** I have posted on a [related topic before](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/open-source-anomaly-detection-in-python), but perhaps this is an interesting side question for a similar audience.